# Ubuntu server - "chmod 644 -R" / as root

Tags: ubuntu

I did something horrible when i was setting up my dedicated server using Ubuntu Server LTS.
When i was setting up a server directory with files in it i wanted full access to the content. So what i originally wanted was to "chmod 755 -R ./" the directory. But i ran the command "chmod 777 -R /" by accident. I then tried to fix it all up but then i by a mistake ran "chmod 644 -R /" - How screwed am i? Now i cannot even chmod or ls. All permissions gone.

Is there a way to fix such issue? I know it's dumb.. And it's properly just me being over my head here... But i really messed up.

Comment: Maybe something for SuperUser or AksUbuntu.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12998/11750

Comment: Can you reboot? If you can boot into recovery mode you can get a root shell (busybox, most commands built-in) and re-chmod `/`. The good(-ish) news is that since / was the first thing to be `chmod`ded, `chmod` couldn't reach any of the other files, so they should be untouched (from their 777 state, and you can see my link above to deal  with that).

Comment: N.b. there's no reason to use `./`, it just makes it easy to make a mistake. If you want to act on the current directory, just use `.`. There are very, very few times the trailing `/` is necessary (and, as you have found, it can lead to trouble).

Comment: Just reinstall the server.